# Initializing ruins my code

Tags: java, variables, loops, for-loop

I'm new to java and I'm currently working on the final project for the semester (CS Major) and I'm running into the "Variable might not have been initialized" error. I've tried other fixes on the site but whenever I do it uses the initialized variable rather than the ones defined in the loop I made.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double priceperpound       = 2;    // price per pound of coffee
    int numberofbags           = 2;    // number of pounds of coffee
    double bagweightinpounds   = 1;    // weight of the bag in punds
//  double pricebeforetaxes    = 8;    // total before taxes
//  double totalpricewithtaxes = 0;    // total price
    double taxrate             = .065; // whats the tax?
    double TotalWeight         = 0;    // total weight of purchase
//  double discountprice       = 0;    // discounted price
//  double discount            = .9;   // if you qualify the price before taxes will be     multiplied by this
    int row;
    int col;

    PriceCalculator calculations = new PriceCalculator(priceperpound, numberofbags,
            bagweightinpounds, taxrate);

    for (bagweightinpounds = 1; bagweightinpounds <= 5; bagweightinpounds = bagweightinpounds + 1) {

        for (numberofbags = 2; numberofbags <= 1024; numberofbags = numberofbags * 2) 
        {
            System.out.printf("%f", calculations.getBasePrice());
        }
    }
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
}
```

Comment: Java is not C or Pascal. Declare the variables only when you need them, and initialize them at the same time, instead of declaring them all at the beginning of the method. And try to create as short methods as possible.

Comment: is this your complete code? because its missing a } in the end.

Comment: Can you put breakpoints and see where exactly you are getting the error please. Not sure if Java compiler gurantees to compile a `double` which is not declared as 0.0, 0.0d or 0.0D... just a thought.

Comment: @bonCodigo: this is a compiler error. Breakpoints won't help.

Comment: I forgot to copy paste the last bracket, and I'm trying to place the delacartions else where within the code but then I get "cannot find symbol" errors

Comment: @user1908047: Don't treat error messages as simple red flags. They contain valuable information, such as the number of the line where the error is, the name of the variable which is not initialized, the symbol that can't be found, etc. Paste your exact source code,  and the exact error message you get.

Comment: the code is exact save for one bracket, here's the error message Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - variable numberofbags might not have been initialized
 at coffeecalculatorv3.CoffeeCalculatorV3.main(CoffeeCalculatorV3.java:30)
Java Result: 1

Comment: This code compiles fine. http://ideone.com/mC7xU9  @user1909047, perhaps the IDE is keeping the old, wrong .class file, delete it.

Comment: You're probably not compiling the code you pasted then. How do you compile?

Comment: Im running the file through netbeans

Comment: Besides, you may wish to move the `PriceCalculator calculations = ` line inside the innermost for loop. What is the point of writing into bagweightinpounds and numberofbags, and not reading them?

Comment: That did it, moving the PriceCalculator calculations into the loop is making it work and run correctly

Comment: When do you expect `for (bagweightinpounds = 1; bagweightinpounds <= 5; bagweightinpounds = bagweightinpounds + 1) {` to end? It makes no sense, `bagweightinpounds = bagweightinpouns + 1` is always false. Use a different variable for the right part of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a variable and give it no default value (for example):

```
int row;
```

if you try to use its value in an expression:

```
row = row + 1;
```

Then the compiler throws an error. Locate the line where the error is located and analyze the variables.

UPDATE: The only variables initialized in loops are in `for` loops, in the first statement (v.g. `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` initializes the `i` variable).

Comment: It will not throw an exception. In fact it will fail to compile.

Comment: But isn't the value initialized at the beginning of the loop? The loops are the only place I can find the code you talking about

Comment: And those are the ones that are giving me errors. If I initialize before the loops then the new values don't take effect while if I don't initialize the code wont compile. ie if I initialize the bagweightinpounds as 2 and number of bags as 1 itll give me fifty 2.0000000 instead of changing the value with each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Its like this.........

- In java when we declare a variable at Class scope ( instance variable), its automatically assigned its default value.
- But when we declare a variable at method scope ( local variable) then it must be initialized before being used.

So in your case do it like this:

int row =0;

int col = 0;

Pardon my code formatting, I am on mobile........